# Can I return water re-circulation to cold inlet port instead of drain port?

Tags: water-heater

I have an electric resistance water heater installed, where hot water re-circulation returns back into drain port as can be seen in the pictures below:

[image]
[image]

The new water heater I am about to install is heat pump water heater; and has ports at completely different locations as can be seen in this picture:

[image]

Have following questions:

1. For the new water heater, can I simply install T connection in cold inlet and connect hot water recirculation return there as well?
2. Would it make any difference at all with regards to hot water recirculation efficiency?
3. Would it make installation easier, as to me it seems that the previous owner had to change drain nipple as it does not have valve and is of different thread size than heat pump water heater.
4. Any reason why previous owner made the recirculation return back to drain port instead of cold inlet?

Comment: Well your current set up 'does not` recirculate, and I will leave you alone, not interested in arguments.

Comment: @Ruskes The current setup does recirculate! I have a pump there behind the water heater that goes into water heater drain port. I have done experiment where I have unplugged pump for a day and immediately noticed that instead of a second it takes minutes for hot water to come out of faucet. My main question still remains - why previous owner went extra mile to recirculate water back into drain port opposed to cold inlet and if for heat pump water heaters considerations are the same.

Comment: Not sure if any of those slightly blurry pictorial symbols in the first diagram represent a check valve, so let me ask: is there a check valve anywhere in the hot water return line or in the pump itself? Because if not, any fixture will draw a blend of hot water from the top of the tank and tepid water from the bottom. Or in the proposed installation, a blend of fully hot and fully cold.

Comment: @MTA I copy pasted that diagram from internet without any considerations to check valves. But you are making a good point about need to have check valve, especially, in proposed scenario where recirc would be connected to cold inlet opposed to drain outlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect no difference in performance or efficiency between using a T at the tank's cold water inlet and using the drain as a return. No idea why the previous owner connected plumbing that way.

When hot water is withdrawn from a point of use, the tank's cold water inlet directs cold water down a dip tube to the bottom of the tank, pretty close to where the drain opening is. So it's six of one, half a dozen of the other whether it's cold water going in or warm water returning from the plumbing system.

Provided that you install a check valve somewhere in the return line beyond the last point of use or use a pump with an internal flow-check as mentioned in my comment above, your system should work fine with the new water heater.